# Wx Python image viewer - atfer opening an image file menu is too tight

Tags: python, user-interface, uiimageview, wxpython, wxwidgets

I use Python 2.7 and wx on Ubuntu 12.04.

I wrote a tiny, tiny image viewer in Python using wx. Everything works just great but I have problems with size of my app's main window.

When I open an ordinary-size picture, I see:

[image]

which is just fine.

But when I open another file, lets say sth like this (an image of a biiiiig graph):

[image]

my app window has a wrong width, I mean take a look at menu its .. too tight and you dont even see an "Edit" option properly.

How to fix it? I just started with wx in Python, so please, be patient :)

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import os

class MyGUIApp(wx.App):

    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):

        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='MyGUIApp v0.2')
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self.frame)

        self.filename = ''
        self.dirname = ''
        width, height = wx.DisplaySize()
        self.pictureMaxSize = 500

        img = wx.EmptyImage(self.pictureMaxSize, self.pictureMaxSize)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.imageCtrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self.frame)

        self.createMenus()  
        self.connectItemsWithEvents()
        self.createKeyboardShortcuts()

        self.frame.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.frame.Show()

    def connectItemsWithEvents(self) :
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.openEvent, self.openItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.clearEvent, self.clearItem)

    def createKeyboardShortcuts(self) :
      self.accel_tbl = wx.AcceleratorTable([(wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('C'), self.clearItem.GetId()),
                                            (wx.ACCEL_CTRL, ord('O'), self.openItem.GetId()),
                                            ])
      self.frame.SetAcceleratorTable(self.accel_tbl)

    def createMenus(self) :
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuFile = wx.Menu()

        self.menuBar.Append(self.menuFile, '&File')      
        self.openItem = wx.MenuItem(self.menuFile, wx.NewId(), u'&open ...\tCTRL+O')
        #self.openItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('images/document-open.png'))
        self.menuFile.AppendItem(self.openItem)

        self.menuEdit = wx.Menu()
        self.menuBar.Append(self.menuEdit, '&Edit')
        self.clearItem = wx.MenuItem(self.menuEdit, wx.NewId(), '&Clear\tCTRL+C')
        #self.clearItem.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap('images/clear.png'))
        self.menuEdit.AppendItem(self.clearItem)


    def openEvent(self, event) :
        openDialog = wx.FileDialog(self.frame, u'Open file', "File", "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)
        if openDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK :
            self.filename = openDialog.GetFilename()
            self.dirname = openDialog.GetDirectory()
            self.draw(os.path.join(self.dirname, self.filename))
        openDialog.Destroy()

    def clearEvent(self, event) :
        img = wx.EmptyImage(self.pictureMaxSize, self.pictureMaxSize)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.frame.SetSize((self.pictureMaxSize, self.pictureMaxSize))
        self.filename = ''
        self.dirname = ''

    def draw(self, filename) :
        image_name = filename
        img = wx.Image(filename, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        W = img.GetWidth()
        H = img.GetHeight()
        if W > H:
            NewW = self.pictureMaxSize
            NewH = self.pictureMaxSize * H / W
        else:
            NewH = self.pictureMaxSize
            NewW = self.pictureMaxSize * W / H
        img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self.frame)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyGUIApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: What result do you expect? Which exact part of your `draw` method do you not understand?

Comment: @phineas: I would love to that when I open an image which has anormous size, I will have scrollbars or sth similar that I could see my whole application gui, not like in my second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call self.Frame.SetMinSize(w, h) to force the window to have a reasonable minimum height and width, but you will want to add scrollbars so that you can see all of the image... I tried to do that but I am a beginner as well and don't have the time at the moment, sorry. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Does the code sample from the question [Creating ScrolledWindow in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392631/creating-scrolledwindow-in-wxpython) help? There is a [`wx.ScrolledWindow`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ScrolledWindow-class.html) class which seems to function like a panel with scrollbars.